# How to list Firestore collections

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get a string array with all the names of collections of a firestore database in angular. I don't know if I explain myself correctly, so I attached a screenshot with what I need.

[image]

I've been searching, and I don't find almost nothing, only a few posts, but I don't understand them.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Comment: in the official documentation I don't see nothing of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

With the Client SDKs (JavaScript, Android and iOS), at the time of writing, you cannot list collections of a Firestore database, nor list sub-collections of a given document.

There are some possible workarounds which are described in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which covers subcollections of a Document but note that the approach is exactly similar for "root" collections of a Firestore database *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

The most interesting one is to use a Callable Cloud Function, because, with the Admin SDK, **you can list (sub)collections** (in this case the [Cloud Firestore Node.js Client API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections)).

The Cloud Function code is quite simple:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getCollections = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const collections = await admin.firestore().listCollections();
    const collectionIds = collections.map(col => col.id);

    return { collections: collectionIds };

});
```

And you would call it from angular using [AngularFireFunctions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md), as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) { 
    const callable = fns.httpsCallable('getCollections');
    this.data$ = callable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already read that answer in another question and I don't understand it.

Comment: Which exact part you don't understand? It is true that it combines different techniques and can be difficult to understand at first read if you are not used to combine these different techniques (in a nutshell, calling from the front end a Cloud Function that reads Firestore)

Comment: I don't understand nothing. Where Have I to put the first code?, In the second code, I don't understand the last line, this.data$ = callable();

What is 'data'$?

Comment: The first code is a Cloud Function. I would suggest that you look at the ["get started" documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and also at the [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series). For the second part I would suggest you dive into the documentation of [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). For the `data$`, I'm not a specialist of Angular, but I think it is simply a convention to indicate that this variable holds an Observable.

Comment: thanks you, I managed to create the function in firebase, but I don't know what to call it. Callable asks for an input parameter.

Comment: ok, problem solved, It's working! Thanks you very much